# iphone cannot connect to Charles

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I'm trying to connect my iphone to charles I've tried for hours and its just not working even after uninstalling and restarting. Out of ideas.

These are the steps I've taken to set this up.

1). Install charles

2). SSL Proxy settings - locations set to *

3). Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate on mobile

4). Both laptop and iphone are connected to the same network

5). Go to wifi network on iphone and change http proxy to server (ip address) port

6). On iphone General->About->Certificate Trust Settings and enable full trust already enabled

The dialogue does not come up to allow traffic on charles.

Any ideas on whats going wrong, I have no VPN running?

Thanks

Comment: It's really interesting. Can you disable SSL inspection and see if that connects ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H not interesting for me unfortunately :( . Disabling SSL Proxying does not work

Comment: Can you check if you data is running ? may be all your requests are routed through data ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H sorry how do I check this?

Comment: Check if you can open local chls/pro on the phone. Then you are connected. After that you can try finding the misconfiguration bug.

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H thanks but going to chls.pro just shows connection timeout

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini thanks cannot connect to chls.pro

Comment: Are you sure you trust everything?

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to open chls.pro/ssl on Safari to download and then install the certificate :-?

In case it's still not working, there is another app named Proxyman and it can inspect requests/ responses on your devices also. I think you might try downloading at https://proxyman.io/ and follow their steps to see if it works. Hope it helps!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add manually your iPhone's IP address to Charles. Go to "Proxy" -> "Access Control Settings" and add here a row with iPhone's local IP address. Maybe that can help you.

[image: Charles' Access Control Settings]

Answer (score 0):

In Access Control Settings select "Prompt to allow unauthorized connections" and then go to charlesproxy.com/ssl on iPhone.